# check if application is already running or restart

Tags: javascript, sql, vb.net, powershell, batch-file

check if application is already running or restart

We can check and restart if a application service is running within SQL. This check can also be done with a SQL JOB. The application is written in old VB and falls over. It needs to be active all the time. So we run the Application.exe when it falls over.

Is there a way to check an exe (i.e Notepad.exe) is running and restart if not. Within SQL 2005\windows script or do we another application (VB) to check.

What will be great to run a SQL script to check if i.e notepad.exe is running and log the result within a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch code demonstrates usage of **tasklist** to find out if an application is running.

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=2" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq Notepad.exe" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%I" == "Notepad.exe" goto AppRunning
)
echo Notepad is not running.
goto :EOF

:AppRunning
echo Notepad is running.
```

For details on the used commands, open a command prompt window, and run there following commands to get help for each command output in the window for reading.

- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `tasklist /?`

---

Command **tasklist** produces a pretty printed output. If the file name of the executable has not the typical 8.3 format, but is much longer, the file name of the executable in list is truncated.

For example the output of **tasklist** is on German Windows XP

```
Abbildname                  PID Sitzungsname      Sitz.-Nr. Speichernutzung
========================= ===== ================ ========== ===============
NotePad012345678901234567  3088 Console                   0         1.984 K
```

on checking for `NotePad012345678901234567890123456.exe` with the command line

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq Notepad*"
```

Note: Wildcard `*` is used in image name filter specification.

The long file name of the executable is truncated to 25 characters.

The following batch code works around the truncation by just checking if the first 7 characters of any running application is `Notepad`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "skip=2" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq Notepad*" 2^>nul') do (
    set "ImageName=%%I"
    if /I "!ImageName:~0,7!" == "Notepad" goto AppRunning
)
echo Sorry, but there is no Notepad* application running.
endlocal
goto :EOF

:AppRunning
echo There is a Notepad* application running.
endlocal
```

It is of course possible to use first batch code with just first 25 characters of the file name of the executable.

Note: Command **for** as used in both batch codes assigns only the string from beginning of third line to first space or tab character to loop variable `I` which is important to know in case of executable contains 1 or more space characters.

Comment: Many thanks this works ok but not for long file names like NotePad012345678901234567890123456.exe - it does recognise long file names in the tasklist. Any work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a windows scheduled task to execute a powershell script with the below code inside.

Save to file AutoStart-MyApplicationName.ps1

```
if (!(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "<Your exe Process name>"})) {Start-Process <path to your exe>}
```

Set your windows scheduled task to run at whatever interval is best for your needs.  The "action" step of your task should be powershell with arguments of "-NoProfile -NoLogo -File c:\AutoStart-MyApplicationName.ps1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TASKLIST` DOS command like below if the exe is running or not

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FI "STATUS eq running"
```

With the comment of @UnknownOctopus, you can use `errorlevel` to see if the `tasklist` command have returned. you can do something like below to achieve what you are after (a sample code ... in your case you can just run the `notepad.exe` if it's not running)

```
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FI "STATUS eq running" > null
if errorlevel 0 ( 
       echo notepad running 
) else (
    echo notepad not running
    )
```

Comment: @UnknownOctopus, Thanks for making that comment. Have included that in answer. Do edit the answer directly if it's valid.

Comment: Many thanks - tested but still echo as running when not loaded.

Comment: This batch code is not working because `tasklist` exits always with code __0__ because it just lists tasks and this is always successful, test on `errorlevel` is made wrong - see Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576), and `null` is a file name and not the device `nul`. I posted a working solution using `tasklist` as one more answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple powershell script which is scheduled to run depending on your needs:

```
$process = Get-Process -Name chrome

if ($process -eq $null)
{
    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
}
```

replace the chrome part with your process name / file path