# Notepad++ run batfile, but Double clicking on .bat doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, notepad++, tasklist

I have an issue with a batfile that would open and run perfectly fine when launch through notepad++, but when manually clicking the .bat file, it will stuck.

The longer I wait before closing it, the longer it will write this once I attempt to close it : ^C^C^C^C^C...

After investigation, it is caused by this line:

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Notepad.exe" | find /i "Notepad.exe" >nul && (
echo NotePad is running
) || (
echo NotePad is not running
)
```

it will not proceed to the next line but stuck on this tasklist command.
same thing happen if I use this instead

```
tasklist | find "notepad.exe" >nul
```

I am not very familiar with scripting, building code through many lines found on internet and got a nice and working thing so far. Any idea what can be causing this ?

Comment: It works fine for me, but try this method, maybe will fix your problem. Insert `if %errorlevel% == 0` between `&&` and `(`, replace `||` with `else`.

Comment: Oh my god ! I think I found why... The script breaks if there is a batfile called Find.bat nearby.

Comment: Do not use just `find` and let command processor find out which find file you mean, use `%SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe` which runs on all Windows (except Win9x) the console application `find.exe` in system directory of Windows. Working on Win9x and all later Windows would be `%windir%\system32\find.exe`.

Comment: @darkfang Console application `tasklist` exits always with return code `0` even if process is not running which is reason for often used `tasklist | find "notepad.exe"` . See [check if application is already running or restart](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31572909/3074564) for a solution without using `find.exe`.